# Webclient with spring boot : Random occurrences of 400 bad request with the same type input data set

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have list of input data ex(ids = 1,2,3,4,5,6...)I am trying to access those(urls like : **https://localhost:8080/1**) using webclient then it is giving 400 bad request for random ids like
In  **https://localhost:8080/1** sometimes I am getting bad request and proper response for the same as well as  some times I am getting bad request **https://localhost:8080/2**  and getting proper response for the same. I am not understanding where it is going wrong. Can anyone help me with this, Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Or figure out what triggered this?

Comment: @bvanvelsen actually there is issue with third party api, after spent lot of I have figured out this. now issue was resolved

Comment: Care to elaborate what third party api? We have a similar issue and it looks like request headers are being duplicated in the request, rendering a '400 bad request'. I wonder if you had the same issue...